# Start a C# Application without a form, but that include forms

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, program-entry-point

I am using MVC in my application, but with a small difference: 4 layers. It contains Model, View, Control and an Orchestrator. This is the main controller, and is the one who says which view controller is active at a time.

Therefore, I must have my entry point calling this Orchestrator class, which will create a controller and this controller will create the view, which will be shown. Whenever the views are closed, the application must stop and finish also.

However, I am not able using Application.Run inside the Main function, in Program.cs to run a class which is not a form. How is it possible to do implement the architecture I wish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [overload of Application.Run that takes an ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx).

The example on that page shows how to use ApplicationContext to exit the app when all of your forms are closed (rather than the default, of exiting when the main form is closed). You should be able to adapt this to your use.

Comment: Should I make my orchestrator an ApplicationContext? Or should I use it to run my Orchestrator and then finish the operation?

Comment: That's up to you, but I might start by making your orchestrator descend from ApplicationContext just for simplicity's sake. If that class seems to be gaining too many responsibilities, you can always split it up later.

Comment: I have been trying to do it, however I found a problem: my application should call an Orchestrator, which would create a controller, and this controller would open the view. However, by making the orchestrator an application context, I could not have the views run by the controller, but by the orchestrator.